# Length of the playing music is wrong

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following piece of code in Python Pygame+Tkinter:

```
def check_event(welcome_msg,time_left):
    global name_songs
    global dir_songs
    #time_left['text'] = (pygame.mixer.music.get_length() - pygame.mixer.music.get_pos())*-1
    if pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()>0:
            time_left['text'] = pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()/1000
    for event in pygame.event.get():          
            if event.type == MUSIC_END and len(name_songs) > 0:
                #print(len(name_songs))
                welcome_msg['text'] = name_songs[0]
                if len(name_songs)!=1:#last song
                        pygame.mixer.music.queue(dir_songs[0])                            
                        dir_songs.remove(dir_songs[0])
                name_songs.remove(name_songs[0])
            #print(pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()/1000)    
                    
    #print(pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()/1000)                
    root.after(1000,lambda:check_event(welcome_msg,time_left))  
def play(music_label,time_left):
    global name_songs
    global dir_songs
    directory=r'C:\Users\Boris\Desktop\songs'
    first_file=0
    pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(MUSIC_END)
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
            f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            # checking if it is a file
            splited_dir=f.split("\\")
            splited_format=splited_dir[len(splited_dir)-1].split('.')
            music_name=splited_format[0]
            name_songs.append(music_name)
            dir_songs.append(f)
            #print(not(first_file),os.path.isfile(f))
            if os.path.isfile(f) and first_file==0:
                    pygame.mixer.music.load(f)
                    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)
                    music_label.configure(text=music_name)
                    name_songs.remove(name_songs[0])
                    dir_songs.remove(dir_songs[0])
            elif os.path.isfile(f) and first_file==1:
                    #queqe next song
                    pygame.mixer.music.queue(dir_songs[0])
                    dir_songs.remove(dir_songs[0])

            first_file+=1
    pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(MUSIC_END)           
    check_event(music_label,time_left)     

def pause():
    #print(tk._default_root,root)    
    if pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        
    elif tk._default_root: #check if window was destroyed
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
```

My problem is that the time that is showing on screen is not correct.
For example,here the song is 3 seconds long,but in the end it only showing 2.074,almost 1 sec difference:

[image]

How to solve this to show the correct length? (for example 3 sec for this music)

Comment: I'd remove the "-1":
`time_left['text'] = (pygame.mixer.music.get_length() - pygame.mixer.music.get_pos())*-1`

Comment: @SiHa That is something I was trying and forget to remove,therfore it is in comment in the code I uploaded.If you mean it should work with this line in place of other line/lines,I would glad for more explanations.